# Create File Path for Listing with Macro based on Arguments

Tags: macros, listings, paths, files, dynamic

I am trying to make a macro that creates the path to a file from which a listing should be loaded based on its parameters.
This fails very early.

Here is a schematic of what I am trying to do:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\RequirePackage{filecontents}%  for creating dummy contents for now
%
\edef\@dummyPath{\jobname.latexgit.dummy}%  the dummy file path
\begin{filecontents*}{\@dummyPath}
blabla
\end{filecontents*}
%
\def\getFilePath#1#2#3{%
\edef\@argA{#1}% <-- if I have this line, it fails
%% do more complicated stuff, return \@dummyPath as fallback if complicated stuff fails
\@dummyPath%
}%
%
\usepackage{listings}%
\begin{document}%
\lstinputlisting{\getFilePath{a}{b}{c}}%
\end{document}%
```

Now, the above is only a somewhat MWE showing my problem.
My macro gets three parameters.
It is supposed to expand the parameters as far as possible (in the future, they may also be macros or something) and do something with them.
It is then supposed to "return" a string denoting a path to a file.
(Sometimes, it may just return the dummy path, as in the example.)

If I `pdflatex example_1.tex`, then I get:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./example_1.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filecontents/filecontents.sty

Package filecontents Warning: This package is obsolete. Disabling it and
(filecontents)                passing control to the filecontents environment
(filecontents)                defined by the LaTeX kernel.

)

LaTeX Info: File `example_1.latexgit.dummy' already exists on the system.
            Not generating it from this source.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file example_1.aux.
! Missing endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   edef 
l.17 \lstinputlisting{\getFilePath{a}{b}{c}}
```

Overall idea:
I am making a tool a bit similar to BibTeX, but for external files.
In other words, if everything works out:

1. On the first `pdflatex` run, the `\getFilePath` would write something to the aux file and always return the path to the dummy file.
2. The aux file would be processed by the external tool and some contents would be added to it.
3. Then in the next `pdflatex` run, `\getFilePath` would return the paths to the actual files.

Now, I can get all of these steps to work, i.e., I can get `\getFilePath` to output actual file paths.
But they do not work in conjunction with anything that actually *uses* the paths, i.e., like `listings` or something.
And this fails already at the point in my MWE where I try to access the parameter values... :-(

Comment: `@` isn't a letter in your preamble. (This isn't the main problem, but it doesn't help.)

Comment: Try to get it working for a simple (non-verbatim) input first. (It is easier with `expl3`.) But I think you need to construct the name first rather than doing it all at once.

Comment: Your `\getFilePath` isn't expandable, and hence can't be used in a file-path argument directly, as those have to be expandable. In effect, you have to either work by expansion only (would mean you're unable to write to the .aux, so impractical), or have to split your approach into two macros: The unexpandable setup so that `\getFilePath` sets an auxiliary macro like `\theFilePath` to the result, and the real access in which you then use `\theFilePath`, so `\getFilePath{a}{b}{c}\lstinputlisting{\theFilePath}`.

Comment: Yes, the `@` slipped in because I used my sty file as basis ...

Comment: OK, so making two sets of commands it is. This sounds like a feasible solution. Thanks.

Comment: Off-topic: You don't need (obsolete) package `filecontents` for years. See [ltnews30.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltnews30.pdf) for more information.

Comment: @cabohah: Indeed, I also noticed this. However, if I understand correctly, this requires that the users have LaTeX at least as new as 2019(?) Sometimes, on some systems or distributions, that might not always be the case. Whereas loading the package simply does nothing on newer systems. So, I thought, who cares ... let's just put it there ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that `\getFilePath` isn't expandable, but you can only use expandable macros where (La)TeX expects a filename.

Unfortunately, you can't expandably write to the AUX file, so your macro can't be expandable by design. If you can't get rid of this AUX-dependency (which I'd guess is unlikely) you'll have to change your approach to a two step solution. Your first step should process your macro arguments and do the unexpandable stuff, and at the end set an auxiliary macro that expands to the chosen name. You can then use that auxiliary for your file accesses.

As an aside: You shouldn't use `\def` on more or less generic macro names directly. You can still use `\def` if you check whether the name is free by using `\@ifdefinable`.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\RequirePackage{filecontents}%  for creating dummy contents for now
%
\makeatletter
\edef\@dummyPath{\jobname.latexgit.dummy}%  the dummy file path
\begin{filecontents*}{\@dummyPath}
blabla
\end{filecontents*}
%
\newcommand*\theFilePath{}% initialising the auxiliary macro
\@ifdefinable\getFilePath{\protected\def\getFilePath#1#2#3{%
  \edef\@argA{#1}% <-- if I have this line, it fails
  %% do more complicated stuff, return \@dummyPath as fallback if complicated stuff fails
  \let\theFilePath\@dummyPath%
}}
\makeatother
%
\usepackage{listings}%
\begin{document}%
\getFilePath{a}{b}{c}%
\lstinputlisting{\theFilePath}%
\end{document}%
```

Comment: I did follow your suggestion. It worked. The result is now visible at https://thomasweise.github.io/latexgit_tex/ as my "latexgit" package, which works together with a Python companion package at https://thomasweise.github.io/latexgit_py. Together, they allow you to load files from `git` repositories into LaTeX documents. The documentation with some examples is available here: https://thomasweise.github.io/latexgit_tex/latexgit.pdf.